# Large Force Directed Graph Dataset in D3/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, graph

I'm using D3 & Angular and I'm having slowdown issues using a large dataset from a .csv parser.
I'm able to load the data and save in my local storage to use, but the graph slows down completely to a crawl once loaded. I'm using Angular on the client side.

Should I load this data up via a server to make it quicker? or

How can I filter the dataset in order for my D3 graph to show?

**D3.component**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.scss']
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('graph');
    const graph = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
    this.loadForceDirectedGraph(graph.nodes, graph.links);

  }

  loadForceDirectedGraph(nodes: Node[], links: Link[]) {
    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    const width = +svg.attr('width');
    const height = +svg.attr('height');

    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeBlues[9]);


    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d: Node) => d.name))// the id of the node
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5).distanceMax(0.5 * Math.min(width, height)))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    console.log(nodes, links);

    const link = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'links')
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', d => Math.sqrt(d.index))
      .attr('stroke', 'black');

    const node = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'nodes')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 8)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.company); })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragEnded)
      );

     node.append('text')
            .text((d) => d.company)
            .attr('x', 6)
            .attr('y', 3);


    node.append('title').text((d) => d.name);

    simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on('tick', ticked);

    simulation.force<d3.ForceLink<any, any>>('link')
      .links(links);

    function ticked() {
      node
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);

      link
          .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
          .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
          .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
          .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);
    }

    function dragStarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) { simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart(); }
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.y;
    }

    function dragEnded(event) {
      if (!event.active) { simulation.alphaTarget(0); }
      event.subject.fx = null;
      event.subject.fy = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How many nodes and links you try to render?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky

Comment: The nodes and links are 8000> rows from a csv file. Im not sure how I can initially filter this.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering more than 10K of elements under SVG is hard. I suppose to filter nodes and links before they're rendered. First, calculate your viewport bounds in your **zoom**() handler and then filter nodes and links by coordinates (render only those inside bounds)

```
const nodeIsVisible = node => 
    (node.x + node.r > 0 && 
    node.x - node.r < width &&
    node.y + node.r > 0 && 
    node.y - node.r < height);
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/q3fjemop/) of 50K ranfomly generated circles filtered by their coordinates. Hope it can give a direction...

Comment: hmm this gives me an idea of what I should do, but it seems like my implementation is a little simpler. How would I do this with my code above?

Comment: @kjamp It can help if you provide a working snippet or fiddle with a limited dataset (~10 nodes/links) so it's possible to see the whole code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-shadow-omdm3?file=/src/app/login/login.component.html I couldn't get it to run but here is my full code

Comment: Your sample does not work (I get CompileError)

Comment: yes, I know I'm not sure if codesandbox supports angular material but I wanted to share my full code for reference

Comment: Better this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-angular-playground

Comment: having a hard time getting this to work with my code above :/